# How to pass days to tikz calendar using macros

Tags: macros, tikz-calendar

I'd like to pass to the calendar some day names using a personal command, so user can change the days easily and create a personal calendar.

I defined the command `\mydays` with one argument, which is passed to the list `\mydayslist`.

How to use this list within the calendar?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}
\mydays{Monday,Friday}

\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last, month list, month label left,%
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt}, month yshift=1.7em, black!20]
%
if (Tuesday) [black] 
% if (\mydayslist) [black] %% <-- insert \mydayslist
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to loop over the contents of the list?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, no. The calendar allows to use `if (Monday,Friday) [black]`.  So I only want to pass the days to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `if` keys to define a style to test *one* day (`myif` in my example). Then you may use an `.expand once` handler (or `.expanded` handler) to expand your macro and a `.list` handler to apply your list.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}
\mydays{Monday,Friday}

\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]

\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last,month list,month label left,
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},month yshift=1.7em, black!20,
myif/.style={if=(#1)[black]},
myif/.list/.expand once={\mydayslist},
];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**First Edit**

An example with `and` condition from [TikZ calendar and conditional tests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140948/tikz-calendar-and-conditional-tests/141027#141027).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/14500
\makeatletter
\def\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iffalse}
\def\pgfcalendar@matchestrue{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iftrue}
\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{and/.code 2 args={%
    \begingroup
      \ifdate{#1}{\ifdate{#2}{\pgfcalendar@matchestrue}{}}{}%
    \endgroup
    \ifpgfcalendar@matches\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse\fi}}
\makeatother
%------
\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}
\mydays{Monday,Friday}

\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]

\calendar (cal) [
dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last,
month list,month label left,
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},
month yshift=1.7em, black!20,
myif2/.style={if={(and={between=2014-04-01 and 2014-05-32}{#1})[red]}},
myif2/.list/.expanded={\mydayslist},
];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Second Edit**

Here is solution mixing [Guho's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294129/14500) and previous solution. I defined a new key `day` to test a list of days:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/calendar/@day/.style={#1},
  /pgf/calendar/day/.style={@day/.list/.expanded=#1},
}
```

With these keys, you may always use the specification syntax (p. 524 of pgfmanual).

Example with `and` condition from [TikZ calendar and conditional tests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140948/tikz-calendar-and-conditional-tests/141027#141027).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/14500
\makeatletter
\def\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iffalse}
\def\pgfcalendar@matchestrue{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iftrue}
\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{and/.code 2 args={%
    \begingroup
      \ifdate{#1}{\ifdate{#2}{\pgfcalendar@matchestrue}{}}{}%
    \endgroup
    \ifpgfcalendar@matches\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse\fi}}
\makeatother
%------
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/calendar/@day/.style={#1},
  /pgf/calendar/day/.style={@day/.list/.expanded=#1},
}
\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}
\mydays{Monday,Friday}

\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]

\calendar (cal) [
dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last,
month list,month label left,
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},
month yshift=1.7em, black!20,
]
if (day=Sunday) [black,font=\itshape]
if (day=\mydayslist) [green]
if (and={between=2014-04-01 and 2014-05-32}{day=\mydayslist}) [red]
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Third Edit**

My third solution defines the macro `\calkeys` (to manage key-value pairs as `\pgfkeys` or `\tikzset` but with `/pgf/calendar/` prefix). With this macro, you may define any calendar selector as a named style:

```
\def\calkeys#1{\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/.cd,#1}}
\calkeys{
  my day list/.style={Friday,Saturday},
  april/.style={between=2014-04-01 and 2014-04-30},
  my day list in april/.style={and={april}{my day list}},
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/14500
\makeatletter
\def\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iffalse}
\def\pgfcalendar@matchestrue{\global\let\ifpgfcalendar@matches\iftrue}
\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{and/.code 2 args={%
    \begingroup
      \ifdate{#1}{\ifdate{#2}{\pgfcalendar@matchestrue}{}}{}%
    \endgroup
    \ifpgfcalendar@matches\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\pgfcalendar@matchesfalse\fi}}
\makeatother
% -----
\def\calkeys#1{\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/.cd,#1}}
\calkeys{
  my day list/.style={Friday,Saturday},
  april 2014/.style={between=2014-04-01 and 2014-04-30},
  my day list in april 2014/.style={and={april 2014}{my day list}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last,month list,month label left,
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},month yshift=1.7em, black!20]
if (my day list) [red]
if (my day list in april 2014) [green]
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But I have to try it with the `and` function from [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/89497).

Comment: @Sigur Where is the problem?

Comment: No problem yet, but I don't see how to combine the codes because I'm using `if (and={between=.... and ....}{my list here}) [black]`.

Comment: @Sigur Done by edit...

Comment: I noticed that you used `myif2`. Could be any name starting with `myif`?

Comment: @Sigur You may use *any* name ! Example: `between 2014-04-01 and 2014-05-32 in red`. Limitation: no `=`, `{`, `}` or `,`.

Comment: Thanks. Your minimal code works but when I merge it in my too long document. no success yet. let me study it.

Comment: @Sigur My second edit provides a better and simpler solution.

Comment: My fault. It works now. Let me study it.

Comment: Should my day list follow mydays?

Comment: @Sigur In my third edit, I removed your command `\mydays`. It's simpler to define a new style as `my day list`...

Comment: I agree that it is simpler but since I'll share the file with people I'd like to create a `sty` and makes edition easier to them simply passing a list of days instead of editing the low level code. Also, using 2 or 3 times the command I can create more calendar at the same page for different schedules. As I said, my cal is very big and sophisticated.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version with a wrapper command for the `tikz` code, that does pre expand the argument (here  `\mydayslist`) -- the usual problem with key value interfaces is the missing expansion of key values, which is the case here!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}


\def\mydayslist{}
\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}

\mydays{Monday,Tuesday,Friday}

\newcommand{\sigurslittlehelper}[1]{%
  if (#1) [black]
  ;
}


\newcommand{\tikzdo}[1]{% Expand the list first, then use the tikz code
  \expandafter\sigurslittlehelper\expandafter{#1}%
}



\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last, month list, month label left,%
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt}, month yshift=1.7em, black!20]
\tikzdo{\mydayslist}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It worked. Thanks. I really have to learn about `\expandafter`.

Comment: @Sigur: Well, most of us should ;-) I am not claiming that I have understood every aspect of `\expandafter` however

Comment: Is it possible to keep the `if ( ) [ ]` code inside `tikzpicture` instead of outside in other command? My code is bigger so I'd like to keep it there for better reading it.

Comment: @Sigur: That's what I have tried so far but I failed. I can understand your issue, however

Comment: `\expandafter` inside `( )` does not work here :-(.

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, I know, that's why my trials failed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. It defines a key to expand the control sequence prior to passing it to the internal `\ifdate`. Derived from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/89497).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\newcommand*{\mydays}[1]{%
 \def\mydayslist{#1}%
}
\mydays{Monday,Friday}
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{fromcs/.code={\expandafter\ifdate\expandafter{#1}{}{}}}%<=====added
\begin{document}

I want to pass the days \mydayslist\ to the calendar.

\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last, month list, month label left,%
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt}, month yshift=1.7em, black!20]
%
if (Tuesday) [black] 
if (fromcs={\mydayslist}) [black] %% <-- insert \mydayslist
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting calendar]

Comment: I got errors `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/calendar/Monday,Friday' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ;` from your code.

Comment: @Sigur: That's what I get for trying to optimize. I removed the `\expandafter`s to see if `\ifdate` would perform the expansion itself. For some reason I thought it worked on my test file, so I edited the answer. Not sure where I went wrong. The post is fixed now. Sorry and thanks for the catch!

Comment: It seems to work. Let me test a little bit more. Thanks.