# How to create a cyclic counter

Tags: tables, counters, count

I am preparing the academic calendar for my institution. It typically looks like the following:
[image]
I will create a `tabular` to fit the data. I have managed to generate the dates by a counter. What I need now is a *cyclic counter* for the days. I want to type `\day[starting day of the month]` in the first row, and `\day` in the successive rows. It should thus generate the entire second column as shown in the above picture. Please help me to achieve that. Following is the code I am working with.

```
\documentclass[9pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=140mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, foot=2.5mm, head=2.5mm, showframe, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{cyan}\leftmark~|~\lastrightmark~|~Academic Calendar 2022-23}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{cyan}Academic Calendar 2022-23~|~\lastrightmark~|~\leftmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\table{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
%
%
%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\color{cyan}Academic Calendar\\2022-23}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
\section{July}
\subsection{Sonada}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & Mon & Type & Content\\ %Want to replace "Mon" by "\day[starting day of the month]"
            \Rownum.    & Tue & Type & Content %Want to replace "Tue" by "\day"
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
\subsection{Siliguri}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & Mon & Type & Content\\ %Want to replace "Mon" by "\day[starting day of the month]"
            \Rownum.    & Tue & Type & Content %Want to replace "Tue" by "\day"
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
%
\end{document}
```

**PS:** I will be extra grateful if you please also guide me about how to type the first 9 dates as "01" till "09". Right now it prints "1" till "9".

Comment: There's [loops - Make a holiday calendar with automatic "school week numbering" in tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453615/make-a-holiday-calendar-with-automatic-school-week-numbering-in-tikz) but it's a bit dense, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use `pgfcalendar`:

```
\documentclass[9pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=140mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, foot=2.5mm, head=2.5mm, showframe, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{cyan}\leftmark~|~\lastrightmark~|~Academic Calendar 2022-23}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{cyan}Academic Calendar 2022-23~|~\lastrightmark~|~\leftmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\ifnum\value{magicrownumbers}<10 0\fi\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\table{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
%
%
%
\newcount\myjdate
\newcount\myweekday
\newcounter{tmpmyjdate}
\newcounter{tmpmyweekday}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\def\wday#1{%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\myjdate}%
\setcounter{tmpmyjdate}{\the\myjdate}%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
\nwday%
}
\def\nwday{%
\ifcase\value{tmpmyweekday} Mon\or Tue\or Wen\or Thu\or Fri\or Sat\or Sun\fi\relax%
\stepcounter{tmpmyjdate}\relax%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\color{cyan}Academic Calendar\\2022-23}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
\section{July}
\subsection{Sonada}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
\subsection{Siliguri}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks much. Apologies for a late response.

Answer (score 1):

In this demo I only give 3 days of week instead of 7. Modify as you want.

Use a mixture of expl3 programming and plain-TeX programming (and needless to say, LaTeX2-style (what's this called?) programming for the counters). Read interface3.pdf and TeXbook/TeX by Topic and the LaTeX companion/unofficial LaTeX2e reference manual for the documentation of commands respectively (alternatively just search around on the site, although some might not have).

Also LaTeX already have a `\day` command, I use `\dayz` here

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

% ** search for "begin insertion" below to see the code. OP gives MWE too long...

\documentclass[9pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=140mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, foot=2.5mm, head=2.5mm, showframe, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{cyan}\leftmark~|~\lastrightmark~|~Academic Calendar 2022-23}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{cyan}Academic Calendar 2022-23~|~\lastrightmark~|~\leftmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\table{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
%
%
%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\color{cyan}Academic Calendar\\2022-23}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
\section{July}


% ======== begin insertion
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{dayofweek}  % 0: sun, 1: mon, ...
\NewDocumentCommand \dayz {o} {
    \IfValueTF {#1} {
        \setcounter {dayofweek} {
            \str_case:nn {#1} {
                {Sun} {0}
                {Mon} {1}
                {Tue} {2}
            }
        }
    } {
        \stepcounter{dayofweek}
        \ifnum \value{dayofweek} = 3
            \setcounter{dayofweek} {0}
        \fi  % wrap around 3 → 0.
    }

    \ifcase \value{dayofweek}
        Sun \or Mon \or Tue  % just for demo.
    \fi
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
% ======== end insertion



\subsection{Sonada}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \dayz[Mon] & Type & Content\\ %Want to replace "Mon" by "\day[starting day of the month]"
            \Rownum.    & \dayz      & Type & Content %Want to replace "Tue" by "\day"
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
\subsection{Siliguri}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \dayz[Mon]  & Type & Content\\ %Want to replace "Mon" by "\day[starting day of the month]"
            \Rownum.    & \dayz       & Type & Content %Want to replace "Tue" by "\day"
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks much. Apologies for a late response. Out of the two working answers I had to choose the other one as it solved the PS question as well. However, yours did teach me how to create a cyclic counter.