# Full weeks in Tikz Calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, calendar

I'm trying to create a monthly calendar using Tikz.

I am using [this template](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/). Everything is working fine, except the fact that I would like to be able to have the numbers of the days from the previous and next months which are in the displayed weeks, like in [this example](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/displaycalendar.shtml) (Figure 7.7). I see that it is possible with PGF. Can I do it with Tikz calendar as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a very simply way with ti*k*Z this can be done using the `dates` key and `if (<test date>) [<style>]` path of the `\calendar` command. Both are well documented in the [PGFmanual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).
There can be more clever solutions. With this solution for example with the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\newcommand{\calOfTheMonth}[4]{%
\calendar [dates=2021-0#1-01+-#2 to 2021-0#1-last+#3,week list,month yshift=0pt]
if (between=2021-0#1-01+-#2 and 2021-0#1-01+-1) [gray]
if (between=2021-0#1-last+1 and 2021-0#1-last+#3) [gray];
\node[above=3ex,anchor=west] {#4};}
\begin{document}
%Explanation of the \calOfTheMonth macro
% \calOfTheMonth{n. of the month}{days to add before}{days to add after}{name of the month}
\tikz
\matrix{
\calOfTheMonth{1}{4}{0}{January}\\
\calOfTheMonth{2}{0}{0}{February}\\
\calOfTheMonth{3}{0}{4}{March}\\
\calOfTheMonth{4}{3}{2}{April}\\
\calOfTheMonth{5}{5}{6}{May}\\
\calOfTheMonth{6}{1}{4}{June}\\
\calOfTheMonth{7}{3}{1}{July}\\
\calOfTheMonth{8}{6}{5}{August}\\
\calOfTheMonth{9}{2}{3}{September}\\
\calOfTheMonth{10}{4}{0}{October}\\
\calOfTheMonth{11}{0}{5}{November}\\
\calOfTheMonth{12}{2}{2}{December}\\
};
\end{document}
```

[image: calendar with full weeks]

Comment: Thanks! Before writing the question, I had tried to set the dates, but I was forgotting `month yshift=0`... However, is it possible to build a macro to automatically calculate the numbers of days to add before and after?

Comment: @jd6 In these days I have worked on a calendar if you are interested this is the [result](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t-jmwjsg_-ydVoOg1L0cuY3Kwix0USaa?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for sharing! The result is very nice! I didn't know the wls format to get the moon phases and the saints. What software do you use to run a wls file?

Comment: It's [wolfram engine for developer](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) with [WolframScript](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html). It's a kind of free version of Mathematica, very powerful for manipulate string of text. I've imported the moon from a NASA web site and the saint of the day from a page of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

With the `ext.calendar-plus` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) we can hack something more automatic together:

This approach uses the following conditions that were [first implemented in another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141027/16595) but are now part of the library mentioned.

- `week of month = <value>`:
  Returns true if the current date is in the `<value>`th week of the month.

  For `week of month = 1` this is basically equal to `between = <month>-01 and <month>-07` but doesn't do as much calculations.
- `week of month' = <value>`:
  Returns true if the current date is in the `<value>`th last week of the month.
- `and = <list of conditions>`:
  Returns true if all conditions in the list evaluate to true

It also uses two new conditions that were created for this answer but are also now part of the library:

- `calendar week of month = <value>`
  Returns true if the current date is in the `<value>`th calendar week of the month.
- `calendar week of month' = <value>`
  Returns true if the current date is in the `<value>`th last calendar week of the month.

They both use the current day and the current weekday to calculate the number of calendar week and compare it with the given value.

The `calendar week of month'` condition uses the `calendar week of month` key but reverses the numbers before it's called.

---

If we now `and` the two conditions

- `week of month = 1` (i.e. first seven days of the week) and
- `calendar week of month = 2` (i.e. the seven days in the second calendar week)

we found those days and week days where we'll want to have another day of the previous week added to our calendar.

The same applies for the end of the week with

- `week of month' = 1` (i.e. the last seven days of the week) and
- `calendar week of month' = 2`.

If these conditions apply we directly execute style `add day from week before` or `add day from week after`. (With “directly” I mean that they're executed even before the actual current day is called – it might be more logical to add this code to `execute at end day scope`.)

Since this is executed as part of the `if`s it might inherit settings that originally apply to the actual current day. However, if we add our `if`s as early as possible, we might be in the clear.

The `add day from week before` and `add day from week after` simulate time travel to the week before/after the currently processed day.

The `\pgftransformyshift` is obviously dependent of the actual style of the calendar, it might be better to put this into the `add day from week …` style so that this code can be better reused for other calendar styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.calendar-plus}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  add day from week before/.default=, add day from week after/.default=,
  add day from week before/.code={%
    \begingroup % shift whole calendar 7 days in the past
      \advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by -7
      \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
      \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday{\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweek{\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<10 0\fi\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgftransformyshift{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day yshift}}%
      \tikzset{every day from week before/.try,#1}%
      \tikzdaycode
    \endgroup},
  add day from week after/.code={%
    \begingroup % shift whole calendar 7 days in the future
      \advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by +7
      \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
      \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday{\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear}{\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \edef\pgfcalendarcurrentweek{\ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<10 0\fi\the\pgfutil@tempcntb}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/day yshift})}%
      \tikzset{every day from week after/.try,#1}%
      \tikzdaycode
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\tikz\calendar[
  dates=2022-01-01 to 2022-03-31, week list, month label above centered,
  % as early as possible
  if = {(and = {week of month = 1, calendar week of month = 2}) [add day from week before]},
  if = {(and = {week of month'= 1, calendar week of month'= 2}) [add day from week after]},
  every day from week before/.style=gray,
  every day from week after/.style={gray,if=(Sunday)[red!25!gray]},
] if (Sunday) [red];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, thanks for your detailed explanation and code!